# Device motion not working on Chrome browse and in phonegap app

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, phonegap

I faced a problem today regarding the device motion event listener in js. If i visit this website http://code.viget.com/device-motion-demo/ with my android phone, on chrome, only the accelerationincludingGravity will be refreshed. If i visit the website with firefox or my phone native browser, everything will refresh. The problem is that my phonegap app does not refresh, like on chrome browser. I have to mention that yesterday everything worked fine and today it is not working and my code is unchanged. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured out that if i disable the chrome app fron my android phone, everything works. So... how can i i gnore the chrome browser from phonegap app to work as it should?

Comment: Update: it looks like the problem is at chrome browser update. I mean that, if i install chrome 63, everything works fine, but if i install the latest version, chrome 65, the device motion is no more working on the phonegap app. So... does the chrome modifyes something in phone's default webview? It happens on an s7 edge, untested on other devices

Comment: Yes. Your phone browser's webview does have an effect on the phone's default webview.

Comment: So...if i publish my phonegap app with some features and chrome will be updated with some bugs/problems regarding my app, my app won't work as it has to, right?

Comment: Ah ok, there's a Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=805146